# How would a fantasy civilization with Napoleonic technology, survive against an uprising of gods such as H.P. Lovecraft's Cthulhu?

Tags: warfare, gods

During an uprising known as "The Awakening" gods begin to appear seemingly out of nowhere all along an empire with a whole continent under its power. They are not gods, per se, but rather immortal beings from once thought to be folklore.

Think of it as if Greek gods sprouted all around the world and attacked the populace. But instead, the humans have muskets, cannons, and airships to defend themselves. These gods do not have any magical powers, *per se*, however, they do have massive effects on people's minds and anyone who observes then will undoubtedly become insane and does the killing for them.

The number is not entirely clear as the royal city has become isolated and reside underground in a place known as the "Godless Embrace".

Because of this awakening, the empire's religions and beliefs are shattered and the massive continent descends into madness. There was, however, a cult that knew of The Awakening long before it happened, but were always thought to be crazy. Now, with the outbreak of these gods, the government turns to this cult for answers.

They say that "The Awakening" happens every ten thousand years as a way of cleansing the earth and making it new. However, during the previous Awakening, a civilization created the only weapon capable of killing these gods.

But in the chaos, a group of rebels stole the weapon and used it to create a unscalable range of mountains surrounding themselves. They did this as a way of protecting it from those who wish to use it for other, more sinister reasons. And that apparently it is still out there waiting to be discovered.

But my question is how these people are fighting off these gods in the meantime.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Worldbuilding! Would you be able to [edit] your question to explain what sort of powers and weaknesses these 'gods'/immortal beings have?

Comment: Welcome to the worldbuilding stackexchange! IMO, your question seems largely opinion-based and too broad and so may be closed. I suggest you edit your question before this happens, providing us with more information about your world. You could start by answering these questions for instance: "What exactly are the capacities of these gods?", "What abilities do they have?", "What can damage them?", "How many of them are there?"

Comment: The description of Gods in your question doesn't sound anything like the "Cuthuthu" in the title. Cuthuthu is more about humanities insignificance in the face of cosmic horror. It has no hitpoints or humanly understandable weaknesses, it's not interested in nation building. You'd survive something like that only by being overlooked. The title is basically a different question.

Comment: @NathanCooper The name of the eldritch abomination is "Cthulhu". I'm not even a Lovecraft fan & I know how to spell the name. I know others are equally guilty, but putting a comment here as a warning to all and sundry seemed fitting. All in the interests of better spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic H.P. Lovecraft style, your gods cause wide spread violent insanity to all in their presence.  This makes them invulnerable to any weapons of the Napoleonic era technology level.  The cannons of that age were line of sight weapons and muskets are only good at less than 100 yards.  Anyone attempting to use such weapons directly against one of the gods will be well within range of the insanity causing visage.  Even if a few are stable (or differently insane) enough to resist the call to violence, they will be surrounded by their fellow armed soldiers who are not.

The first battles would be horrific but might just be educational enough to give the humans a chance.  By studying those who can resist the effect (even partially), the leaders might determine what types of personalities favor survival.  Maybe megalomania, mild dementia and border-line psychosis are all helpful on this new battlefield.  Maybe the rebellious and the disobedient, who have little regard for human law and discipline, have an easier time viewing the gods whose existence bends the physical laws.  Maybe such mad and wild men can get close enough to a god to fire a musket at them.  Then we would learn if survival, even through insanity, is even possible.

If all else fails, you can always issue hallucinogenic drugs to your troops.  Maybe physical insanity plus biochemical insanity can merge to form something approaching what we call sane.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, this is my first time :) Check my edits and see what you think now.

Comment: Okay, I now see that this isn't our world minus 200 years but a separate world all together.  I will change my answer to suit.

Comment: It seems like muskets would take so long to penetrate Cuthulu's skin that he would actually grow new skin faster than it was injured. Depends how thick and strong his skin is, and how fast it regrows.

Comment: @Braydon The name of the eldritch abomination is "Cthulhu". I'm not even a Lovecraft fan & I know how to spell the name. I know others are equally guilty, but putting a comment here as  a warning to all and sundry seemed fitting. All in the interests of better spelling.

Comment: @a4android, Thanks for catching and correcting my 3 spelling mistakes.  Spelling, at least as the word applies to writing, has never been my strong suit.

Comment: @Braydon Cthulu regenerates pretty fast. He had his head sliced all the way through by a speeding boat and he grew it all back in the span of a few seconds. So... I don't really think muskets are the way to deal with a eldritch abomination. Perhaps eldritch magic would be more suited to combating the elder gods? If no magic, then maybe fire. Fire would damage many more cells than muskets ever could, and would be fueled by the oxygen around them and the continuously dividing cells.

Comment: That's OK. All part of the service. It's a good answer and only needed a bit of polishing.