# Reason for magical abilites

Tags: magic

In my fantasy universe there are people called *Naorein* that can control the world around them, bending it and using it to their will. However, it is all small scale, like people creating small handholds for climbing or seeing what's behind a wall.

In this empire, these people are thought to be disciples of the god *Rèin*, the god of the empire's official religion, *Reinism*. However, these *Naorein* are born with varying strength, and those that do not fit a certain criteria are shunned. Those that are thought to be more powerful are brought to the royal city and integrated into the empress's royal guard. In this royal city, the *Naorein*'s powers seem to spike in strength. Because of this it is thought to be the holiest place in all the empire.

However, it is later found out this is because of a super weapon located under the city. During the course of the story, a rogue *Naorein* is hired to assassinate someone in the royal city, but when he gets there he realizes that it was a double cross and the whole mission was a trap to heard him into the royal palace along with every other rogue *Naorein*. Once they have him they need to use all the captured *Naorein* for something about this weapon.

The problem is, I don't know what. I also want it to be that these *Naorein* are in some way connected to this weapon. If you have any additional questions about the weapon please go check out my first question:

[How would a fantasy civilization with Napoleonic technology, survive against an uprising of gods such as H.P. Lovecraft's Cthulhu?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/94295/how-would-a-fantasy-civilization-with-napoleonic-technology-survive-against-an)

Comment: Why are certain Naorein captured? Are these the powerful users who are to be integrated into the guard? Also what is special about your main character that there would be a reason to lure him in to the palace?

Comment: Well, they are captured to use then for something about the weapon. The Naorein that reach a certain level of strength in their power are brought to the royal palace to be in the empress's royal guard. And they are luring all Naorein in for this weapon, but the ones that are not rogue are already at the palace in the first place.

Comment: Hello *Unhappymarshmellow* (sad and at the same time cute profile pic by the way)! A little tip: questions that are formatted often fare better as it's far easier to read for people. It's also important to include all the relevant information in your question. Every question should be self-contained. Brainstorming is also off-topic on WorldBuilding. Please visit the [help/dont-ask] to learn more about this. Have you ruled out ways you do not want to use? That may help in narrowing down the scope so that there could be a real *best* answer. Have fun on the site!

Comment: @Secespitus Yeah, sorry for making an inappropriate question for the site. I just find it very difficult to form a well organized and appropriate question to ask.

Comment: That's pretty normal. In case you are interested: there is a [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on Meta that is designed to help people who feel a question might be difficult for the site or who would like others to check for example their grammar before posting on the Main Site. The [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) is also great for brainstorming or to get feedback for questions. No need to apologize and looking forward to your question!

Comment: Oh, and just because your question is "on hold" now doesn't mean it couldn't theoretically get reopened. During the "on hold" period an [edit] from yours would automatically put it into a "reopen" review queue so others can judge whether the new version fits the sites scope. Only after a week without any activity from your site would "close" this question, meaning someone with more than 3,000 reputation would have to manually click on the "reopen" link on your qestions site to send it to that queue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution would be to "Reload" the weapon. If they don’t regularly do this ritual their magic booster runs out.

There are an infinite number of tropes you could use. Save the world. Conquer the world etc.

P.S. This question might be considered off topic due to its idea generating nature.

Answer (score 0):

> In this royal city, the Naorein's powers seem to spike in strength

Seem's to me you have already answered this question

> I also want it to be that these Naorein are in some way connected to this weapon.

So sure presence of the power can be hereditary but the weapon acts as an amplifier increasing their strength. It could be that those who inherited the power descend from those who either created or were able to master the weapon.

As for:

> they need to use all the captured Naorein for something about this weapon. The problem is, I don't know what.

They could be used as sacrifices to power the weapon.

It could be that the weapon entrusted its power to certain ancestors and wants to reclaim that power through sacrifice of their descendants.